# Taking multiple optimization steps on the same trajectory not well justified.

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I am reading the paper Proximal Policy Optimization Algorithms found at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06347.pdf. In this paper they say "While it is appealing to perform multiple steps of optimization on this loss $L^{PG}$ using the same trajectory, doing so is not well-justified". The question I have is why is using the same trajectory not well justified? If you have a stochastic environment you may get the same trajectory over and over give the same action. What am I missing about policy gradient methods that makes this unjustified. Is there a paper or text I could read to fill in the gap? Or is this an obvious logical leap I'm missing? Sorry, my first time posting on math stack exchange, please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Where $L^{PG}(\theta) = \hat{\mathbb{E}}_t[\log \pi_{\theta}(a_t | s_t) \hat{A_t}]$.

$\pi_{\theta}$ is a stochastic policy,

$\hat{A_t}$ is an estimator of the advantage function at time step t.

$a_t$ is the action taken at time step t.

$s_t$ is state given at time step t.

The expectation is $\hat{\mathbb{E}}_t[\cdots]$ is the
empirical average over a finite batch of samples.

Comment: Guessing based on the next section in the paper, maybe we can only trust the model to be valid locally. Trust Region methods are often applied when we have a limited region in which we can trust our simplifications. We then need to update to build a new region for which we can trust our estimations or if we continue outside of our trusted region we may end up fumbling around in the dark because our model is no longer valid.